# Pip: could not find a version. No matching distribution found

Tags: python, pip, package

I'm trying to install Flask-ACL:
https://mikeboers.github.io/Flask-ACL

```
$ pip search acl | grep -i flask

Flask-ACL (0.0.1) - Access control lists for Flask.
flask-miracle-acl (0.2) - The fabric between the Flask framework and Miracle ACL

Flask-Sandbox (0.1.0)- ACL Route controls for Flask
Flask-SimpleACL (1.2)- Simple ACL extension


$ pip install Flask-ACL

Collecting Flask-ACL
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask-ACL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask-ACL
```

What's wrong here?

P.S. Pip was upgraded a few minutes ago.

UPDATE:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

I'm running it under virtualenv.

```
pip install -Iv Flask-ACL

Collecting Flask-ACL
1 location(s) to search for versions of Flask-ACL:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask-acl/
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask-acl/
Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask-acl/" in the cache
Current age based on date: 507
Freshness lifetime from max-age: 600
Freshness lifetime from request max-age: 600
The response is "fresh", returning cached response
600 > 507
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask-acl/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask-ACL (from versions: )
```

Cleaning up...
  No matching distribution found for Flask-ACL

As I can see, there is no such package on Pypi:

```
https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask-acl/
```

but this one exist:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-ACL
```

What is wrong with my `pip`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The developers of Flask-ACL made a mistake that they did not manage to upload the Flask-ACL library onto PyPi(where pip searches for modules). so you will have to install it using pip from their GitHub page.

You can do so like this:

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/mikeboers/Flask-ACL"
```

Comment: I do know this workaround, but may I install this without direct link using `pip install` as for other packages?

Comment: If you look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-ACL there is no .whl links to it.

Comment: this is the root of issue?

Comment: As I see it, yes

Comment: ok, it sounds realistic. If I'll not have another explanation, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Have had the same problem with https://github.com/SimFin/pdf-crawler installing with

pip install "git+https://github.com/SimFin/pdf-crawler"
Finally worked.

Comment: To fully solve the problem the ideal action would be to contribute PyPI distribution to the project, since it's open source. Perhaps someone will do that for them one day.

Comment: I have the same problem with Aspose.Words. I'm trying to install the through pip. Getting the same error. How do I know the link for Aspose.Words as shown for flask?

Answer (score 8):

A more common reason for this type of error is probably that your environment does not meet the package's requirements.

For example, this occurs if your environment's Python version does not match the required Python version specified by the package:

```
(my_python36_env)> pip install package_that_requires_python37

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package_that_requires_python37.
ERROR: No matching distribution found for package_that_requires_python37.
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention if your file `~/.pip/pip.conf` not contain any additional `index-url` values. 
Then it can trying to look for specific package version in repository that not exists.

Some workaround solution is to remove pip.conf

Answer (score 0):

I had flask installed in the anaconda but it had some issues when it import it using

`from tensorflow.keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions`

so instead of the above command, i changed it to

`from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions`

and it worked fine