# Anaconda3, Python 3.6 - pip install imagenet_utils - error message: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement imagenet_utils

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Anaconda3, Python 3.6, pip version 9.0.1

```
pip install imagenet_utils
```

Error message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement imagenet_utils  (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for imagenet_utils

Please, help.

Comment: Thanks for edit @SurvivalMachine.

Answer (score 0):

Read me docs on github indicate compatibility up to 3.5. Take a look at some comparable libraries to avoid this issue here:
[5 Genius Python Deep Learning Libraries](https://elitedatascience.com/python-deep-learning-libraries).

Anaconda also offers a conda install version of Keras where this specific package can be accessed:

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

then for python script would read:

```
from keras import imagenet_utils
```

Assuming compatibility is not the issue, you will need to verify the anaconda package location and make sure that you are installing to that location.

Comment: Thank you. But this answer still can not solve my problem.

Comment: check out the answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987521/pip-could-not-find-a-version-no-matching-distribution-found

Comment: pip install https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py

Collecting https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py
  Downloading https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py
     / 163kB 80kB/s

Error Message:
 Cannot unpack file C:\Users\hdpc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-knvgqycs-unpack\imagenet_utils.py

Comment: supported scheme: "pip install git+https://...git" should address that issue. your install is missing the "git+".