# Not able to install ifxpy package using pip3 install on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, informix

I tried to install ifxpy package in windows machine but getting error

```
Collecting IfxPy
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement IfxPy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for IfxPy
```

I tried the following commands:

```sh
$ pip3 install IfxPy
$ pip3 install ifxPy
$ pip3 install IfxPy==3.0.3
```

I have downloaded wheel file and tried this command:

```sh
$ pip install IfxPy-3.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

error :- ERROR: IfxPy-3.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Please find the error which i got after import

> > > import IfxPyDbi
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Users\AmanAgrawal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IfxPyDbi.py", line 85, in 
> > >           import IfxPy
> > >       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What platform are you trying to install the package on?

Comment: The wheel file you downloaded is for Python 3.7 on 64bit Windows.

Comment: Thanks Tim for quick reply
I am trying on python 3.6 on 64bit windows
Could you please tell me how to install via pip or where i can get python 3.6 wheel?

Comment: First search for the package on pypi.org and check which packages are available. It looks like they have only released a single file for Python 3.7 with the latest release. Either you are going to have to get the source code and build yourself, or open a bug request with the IFxPy team to get additional packages built.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip: could not find a version. No matching distribution found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987521/pip-could-not-find-a-version-no-matching-distribution-found)

Comment: Thanks!!! @Tim for quick reply

I have installed ifxpy module.

Collecting ifxpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/01/38f7267e68270164b38da4617e501aa41c9be1179bd16bba5c086172db14/IfxPy-3.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: ifxpy
Successfully installed ifxpy-3.0.3

Comment: Thanks!! @AndrasDeak for quick reply

But I tried to import I got the below error

>>> import IfxPyDbi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AmanAgrawal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IfxPyDbi.py", line 85, in <module>
    import IfxPy
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy/blob/master/LocalBuildWindows.md)? Sounds like an incomplete install.

Comment: Hi @AndrasDeak ,

If I want to use ifxpydbi module in docker container how i will proceed ??

I have already added in requirement file and container is created successfully. But when i tried to import inside the container it throws the same error.

Comment: That error is caused by the compilation failing and getting a partial install. Again you need to go back to the project owners and ask them to publish wheels for all the python versions they claim to support, use an older version, or compile yourself from source.

Comment: Did you install CSDK before trying to build the module? IfxPy needs the ODBC libraries and include files which are shipped with Informix CSDK. 
You need to get the 64-bit version, search for something like 4.10.FC12

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try a manual install of IfxPy-3.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
It can be downloaded from [IfxPy version 3.0.1 for windows x64](https://pypi.org/project/IfxPy/3.0.1/#files)

We will help you fix the real problem; meanwhile for you to proceed with the operation you are trying, as a workaround please download the IfxPy.zip from 
https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy/blob/master/prebuilt/3x/Win64/IfxPy.zip
and unzip it the same directory as your sample application you are trying. This should allow the sample application to work. Then to pinpoint the problem we would like to have bit more information, can you please provide output of the following from the same command window that you got error.

```
python -V
pip –V
pip3 –V
set PATH
```

Also the full error log also will help.

Comment: Thanks @Satyan for reply 
I have Installed wheel for both 3.6 and 3.7 version but still error persist. 
Please find the error

>>>import IfxPyDbi as dbapi2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<Path>\site-packages\IfxPyDbi.py", line 862

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: We will help you fix the real problem; meanwhile for you to proceed with the operation you are trying, as a workaround please download the IfxPy.zip from 
https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy/blob/master/prebuilt/3x/Win64/IfxPy.zip
and unzip it the same directory as your sample application you are trying. This should allow the sample application to work. Then to pinpoint the problem we would like to have bit more information, can you please provide output of the following from the same command window that you got error. 

python -V
pip –V
pip3 –V
set PATH

Comment: python -V

I have 2 python installed 
Python 3.7.4 (64bit)
Python 3.6.2 (32bit)

pip –V

pip 19.1.1 from both (python 3.7 and 3.6)

Enviornment variable :-
CSDK_HOME
C:\Program Files\IBM Informix Client SDK
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM Informix Client SDK

MY_PY_DIR
Python directory

Comment: >set PATH
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Cloud Foundry;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;

Comment: C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Users\AmanAgrawal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\AmanAgrawal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\AmanAgrawal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Users\AmanAgrawal\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\AmanAgrawal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Comment: Thanks for the informaiton, I couldn't find anyting unusual with the setting you have. Can you please try IfxPy.zip to the same directory as your application, the you will see the folloing two files. 
IfxPyDbi.py and IfxPy.cp36-win_amd64.pyd

Comment: Then please rename IfxPy.cp36-win_amd64.pyd to IfxPy.pyd And then please try runing the python applicaiton you were triying previously, this is expected to work, If this work then we can conclue you don't have any runtime problem with the driver. Then what remain is the install related problem, we will get that also addressed.

Comment: Thanks @Satyan for helping me out to all the queries we have resolved out problem by installing python 3.6 64 bit version.